# How do I match any sequence of letters and "something else" in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I want to match any sequence of letters with some other special characters, say `:` and `;`. Here's what I've tried to do:

`/[\w;:]*`

But this just seems to match *everything*. The [VIM documentation](http://vimregex.com/#anchors) gives `[Vv]` as an example for a regexp that can locate either `V` or `v`, and sure enough this seems to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to match any sequence of letters with some other special characters, say : and ;

```
[A-Za-z:;]*
```

`\w` not only includes letters but also  digits and underscore symbol. `*` repeats the previous token zero or more times.

Answer (score 1):

The `\w` atom doesn't work inside a *collection*. You need to either use *branches*:

```
/\%(\w\|[;:]\)*
```

but it's easier to look up the character ranges via `:help /\w` and put those into the collection:

```
/[0-9A-Za-z_;:]*
```

There are also several *character classes*; there's none for `\w`, but `[:alnum:]` comes close, missing only the `_`:

```
/[[:alnum:]_;:]*
```

**Note: If you really just want *letters*, that would be `\a` or `[:alpha:]`.**